# How to put header and footer on titlepage in scrreprt?

Tags: titles, scrlayer-scrpage, scrreprt

I have to put a header and footer onto an entire document, but I'd still like to use the titlepage in `scrreprt`.

I tried doing this:

```
\documentclass[fleqn, 11pt, a4paper]{scrreprt}

\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}

\ihead{ihead}
\ohead{ohead}
\chead{chead}

\pagestyle{scrheadings}
\renewcommand{\titlepagestyle}{scrheadings}

\title{\Huge title}
\subtitle{\Large subtitle}
\author{person a \and person b}
\date{15.11.2016}
\publishers{none}

\begin{document}

\begin{titlepage}
    \thispagestyle{scrheadings}
    \maketitle
\end{titlepage}

\newpage 

aasdasdsdads

\newpage

\end{document}
```

But to no avail, the Titlepage is still without headers and footers.

They work fine with `scrartcl`, but well - not with `scrreprt`. How can I force them onto the titlepage?

Comment: The koma-script documentation says that you shouldn't put `\maketitle` in a `titlepage` environment. Use the one or the other but not both.

Comment: @PietvanOostrum OK, I'll do that, but I still don't know how to accomplish what I'm after... Thanks for the tip, though.

Answer (score 2):

`\titlepagestyle` is only supported on a so-called *in-page* title (.ie. not in a `titlepage`). This is indicated by the option `titlepage=false`. See pages 58, 59 of the koma-script documentation (English). The class `scrartcl` uses *in-page* by default.

The combination that works is:

```
\documentclass[  titlepage=false]{scrreprt}
...
\renewcommand{\titlepagestyle}{scrheadings}
...
\newpage
\maketitle
\newpage
```

Here is a complete example

```
\documentclass[fleqn, 11pt, a4paper, titlepage=false]{scrreprt}

\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}

\ihead{ihead}
\ohead{ohead}
\chead{chead}

\pagestyle{scrheadings}
\renewcommand{\titlepagestyle}{scrheadings}

\title{\Huge title}
\subtitle{\Large subtitle}
\author{person a \and person b}
\date{15.11.2016}
\publishers{none}

\begin{document}

\newpage
\maketitle
\newpage 

Some text

\newpage

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

If option `titlepage=true` (default for `scrreprt`) is set, `\maketitle` itself uses environment `titlepage` for the title pages.

You could patch `\maketitle` to ensure that `\titlepagestyle` is used on the page with the title:

```
\documentclass[fleqn]{scrreprt}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}
\ihead{ihead}
\ohead{ohead}
\chead{chead}

\usepackage{xpatch}
\xpatchcmd\maketitle
  {\huge \@title}{\Huge \@title\thispagestyle{\titlepagestyle}}
  {}{\PatchFailed}
%\makeatletter
%\xpatchcmd\@maketitle% this command is used if titlepage=false is set
  %{\huge \@title}{\Huge \@title}
  %{}{\PatchFailed}
%\makeatother

\renewcommand\titlepagestyle{scrheadings}

\addtokomafont{subtitle}{\Large}

\title{title}
\subtitle{subtitle}
\author{person a \and person b}
\date{15.11.2016}
\publishers{none}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
aasdasdsdads
\end{document}
```

Comment: The `titlepage` environment doesn't do much more than switching to `onecolumn` if `twocolumn` was in effect, and setting `\thispagestyle{empty}`. So it is not a big loss not to use a `titlepage` environment, but set up your own page.